# Which is the best branch to submit a pull request to Rails on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, open-source, github

I've created a patch for Rails that I would like to submit to the community for consideration.

At the moment, development is happening on two separate major versions (3 and 4) and so I'm not sure which branch I should send my pull request to?

**master**?
**3-2-stable**?

Also, which version of Rails should I rebase my patch on before I send the pull request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**According to this page** http://guides.rubyonrails.org/contributing_to_ruby_on_rails.html#issue-a-pull-request, there is no particular branch in which you should submit a pull request.

I also checked in the recent pull requests in rails (https://github.com/rails/rails/pulls) and it looks like most of them are requesting pull into `master`.

Anyway, assume Rails core team want to merge your branch somewhere else, they will just do it manually. Don't worry and just open your pull request !